# How to do this in nhibernate queryover

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-projections

I need to do this in nhibernate QueryOver:

```
select distinct sc.* from [Security].[Commands] sc
inner join [Security].[SystemSubjects] ss on ss.Id = sc.Id
left outer join [Security].[SystemSubjectRoles] ssr on ssr.SystemSubjectId = ss.Id
left outer join [Security].[Roles] sr on sr.Id = ssr.RoleId
left outer join [Security].[UserRoles] ur on ur.IdRole = sr.Id 
left outer join [Security].[User] su2 on su2.Id = ur.IdUser
left outer join [Security].SystemSubjectUsers ssu on ssu.SystemSubjectId = ss.Id
left outer join [Security].[User] su on su.Id = ssu.UserId
where (su2.Id = 1 or su.Id = 1)
```

So far I have done this:

```
var queryOverRoles = QueryOver.Of<Command>(() => cmdAlias)
            .JoinAlias(() => cmdAlias.SystemSubjectRoles, () => ssRoleAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .JoinAlias(() => ssRoleAlias.Role, () => roleAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .JoinAlias(() => roleAlias.Users, () => userAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .JoinAlias(() => cmdAlias.SystemSubjectUsers, () => ssUserAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .JoinAlias(() => ssUserAlias.User, () => userAlias2, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
            .Where(() => ssRoleAlias.SecurityPermission == SecurityPermission.Allow)
            .And(() => (userAlias.Id == userId || userAlias2.Id == userId))
```

but this selects all (Select *) and I want only the Command object (select sc.*).
If I try to add a projection to the query like this:

```
queryOverRole.Select(x=>x);
```

it throws  this exception:

> ```
> System.Exception was caught   Message=Could not determine member
> ```
>
> from x   Source=NHibernate
>   StackTrace:
>          at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberExpression(Expression
>   expression) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionProcessor.cs:line
>   189
>          at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2.Select(Expression`1[]
>   projections) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Criterion\QueryOver.cs:line
>   363
>          at Novatec.Persistence.Repositories.Implementations.UserRepository.GetAllowedUserCommands(Int32
>   userId) in
>   C:\Projects\EGrad\Main\Source\Novatec.E-Grad\Source\Novatec.Persistence\Repositories\Implementations\UserRepository.cs:line
>   140
>          at Novatec.Administracija.Services.Security.SecurityManager.AuthorizeUserAction(Int32
>   userId, String commandId) in
>   C:\Projects\EGrad\Main\Source\Novatec.E-Grad\Source\Novatec.Administracija.Services\Security\SecurityManager.cs:line
>   48
>          at Novatec.Framework.Infrastructure.Services.ServiceBase.ExecuteCommand(Int32
>   userId, String appId, ICommand
>   command) in
>   C:\Projects\EGrad\Main\Source\Novatec.E-Grad\Source\Novatec.Framework.Infrastructure\Services\ServiceBase.cs:line
>   94   InnerException:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.... you need to specify which alias to select.
queryOverRole.Select(result => cmdAlias);